# Spark: explode multiple columns into one

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is it possible to explode multiple columns into one new column in spark? I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
userId         varA     varB
   1         [0,2,5]   [1,2,9]
```

desired output:

```
userId     bothVars
   1         0     
   1         2     
   1         5  
   1         1  
   1         2  
   1         9
```

What I have tried so far:

```
val explodedDf = df.withColumn("bothVars", explode($"varA")).drop("varA")
                   .withColumn("bothVars", explode($"varB")).drop("varB")
```

which doesn't work. Any suggestions is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap the two arrays into one and [`flatten`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@flatten(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) the nested array before exploding it, as shown below:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, Seq(0, 2, 5), Seq(1, 2, 9)),
  (2, Seq(1, 3, 4), Seq(2, 3, 8))
).toDF("userId", "varA", "varB")

df.
  select($"userId", explode(flatten(array($"varA", $"varB"))).as("bothVars")).
  show
// +------+--------+
// |userId|bothVars|
// +------+--------+
// |     1|       0|
// |     1|       2|
// |     1|       5|
// |     1|       1|
// |     1|       2|
// |     1|       9|
// |     2|       1|
// |     2|       3|
// |     2|       4|
// |     2|       2|
// |     2|       3|
// |     2|       8|
// +------+--------+
```

Note that `flatten` is available on Spark `2.4`+.

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_union` and then use `explode` function.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+------+---------+---------+
|userId|varA     |varB     |
+------+---------+---------+
|1     |[0, 2, 5]|[1, 2, 9]|
|2     |[1, 3, 4]|[2, 3, 8]|
+------+---------+---------+
```

```
scala> df
.select($"userId",explode(array_union($"varA",$"varB")).as("bothVars"))
.show(false)

+------+--------+
|userId|bothVars|
+------+--------+
|1     |0       |
|1     |2       |
|1     |5       |
|1     |1       |
|1     |9       |
|2     |1       |
|2     |3       |
|2     |4       |
|2     |2       |
|2     |8       |
+------+--------+
```

`array_union` is available in Spark `2.4+`

Comment: It should be cautioned that `array_union` will keep only one copy of any overlapping elements between the arrays.